# Run Autosys commands from command line in Linux

Tags: bash, autosys

I am trying to run Autosys commands from the command line. 
I have been given a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/casper/dist/java/sunjre/1.6.0_25/exec
export IXP_HOME=/casper/dist/tpcommon/ixp/latest/common
export PATH=$PATH:$IXP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export AUTOSERV=PAA
export IXP_SERVER_URL="http://usa-autosys-p.casper.com"
```

I copied that script to /tmp/autosys_foo

This is the contents of $IXP_HOME/bin:

```
$ ls -ltr /casper/dist/tpcommon/ixp/latest/common/bin/
total 112
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixviewfile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixsendevent
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixjob_depends
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixjil
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixflags
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixautostatus
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixautorep
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixautocal_asc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 10463 Feb  4  2016 ixagent
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   385 Feb  4  2016 a
```

When I run this I get nothing

```
$ /tmp/autosys_foo ixautorep CASPER_AUTOSYS_JOB -q
```

When I run the absolute path I get this error

```
$ /casper/dist/tpcommon/ixp/latest/common/bin/ixautorep -J CASPER_AUTOSYS_JOB -q
IXP_HOME not set
```

Comment: Your /tmp/autosys_foo script has just the export commands.  It doesn't do anything else and doesn't output anything.

Comment: Probably, you need this: `source /tmp/autosys_foo; /casper/dist/tpcommon/ixp/latest/common/bin/ixautorep -J CASPER_AUTOSYS_JOB -q`.